# I am getting 400 bad request error while trying to upload image to aws s3 bucket using preSignedUrl. What is going wrong?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using IAM configuration for my bucket and nodejs on backend. I searched for solution whole night. But unable to find the answer.

This my policy configuration for user on aws:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-first-bucket-stephengr/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-first-bucket-stephengr",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:041892289571:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:041892289571:job/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Code on backend:
app.get("/api/upload", loginRequired, function(req, res){

```
  var key = `${req.user.id}/${uuid()}.png`;
  var fileName = key.split("/")[1];

  s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", {
      Bucket: "my-first-bucket-stephengr",
      ContentType: "image/png",
      Key: key

  }, (err, url) => {
      res.json({key, url, fileName});
  })
```

})

Code on front end:
async function handleSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault();

```
    var res = await axios.get("/api/upload", {headers: authHeader()});

    try{
    
        await axios.put(res.data.url, file, {headers: {ContentType: file.type}})

    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }

    console.log(res.data);
}
```

Comment: Upload how? Any details?

Comment: I have included the code in my question? Anyone help ?

Answer (score 3):

error was due to region. Adding region property on the backend fixed the issue:

```
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: "ap-south-1"
    })
```